# Destroyed Bullet Won't Make Clones and Shoot After around 3 seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script that shoots a bullet and destroys it after 3 seconds, however it destroys the original bullet after it is shot which makes unity unable to make copies of it to shoot another bullet, An okay solution might be to make a copy of the bullet and shoot the copy however I do not know how to do that.

This is the script for the gun

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunShootingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public ParticleSystem MuzzleFlash;
public float damage = 10f;
public float range = 100f;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public float bulletLife = 3f;

public Camera playerCamera;
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        Destroy(bulletPrefab, bulletLife);
        Shoot();
    }
}
void Shoot()
{
    MuzzleFlash.Play();
    Instantiate(bulletPrefab, playerCamera.transform.position, playerCamera.transform.rotation);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.transform.position, playerCamera.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        TakeDamage target = hit.transform.GetComponent<TakeDamage>();
        if(target != null)
        {
            target.GiveDamage(damage);
        }

    }

}
}
```

This is the script for the bullet.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shot : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
public float speed = 3000f;

void Update()
{
    transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
}
```

Comment: Shoot();  Destroy(bulletPrefab, bulletLife);

Comment: Shoot() first and destory orgin bullet

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you destroy the bulletPrefab but you never actually assign an object for it. You can have a separate GameObject and do that when instantiating inside the Shoot method. Try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunShootingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public ParticleSystem MuzzleFlash;
public float damage = 10f;
public float range = 100f;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public float bulletLife = 3f;
private GameObject bulletShot // This is what I added

public Camera playerCamera;
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        Destroy(bulletShot); // Removed the timer from here
        Shoot();
    }
}
void Shoot()
{
    MuzzleFlash.Play();
    bulletShot = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, playerCamera.transform.position, playerCamera.transform.rotation); // Assigned the bullet to the separate GameObject
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.transform.position, playerCamera.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        TakeDamage target = hit.transform.GetComponent<TakeDamage>();
        if(target != null)
        {
            target.GiveDamage(damage);
        }

    }

}
}
```

That way, when you try to destroy it, there will actually be something to destroy. However, this will create a new issue. The previously instantiated object will be destroyed instantly when you shoot again. You can fix that by creating a list and adding the bullets there. However, that is NOT efficient. And since you are going to start all over, I suggest you go for an Object Pool. What is that? Glad you asked!

There is a very good video by Jason Weimann on YouTube about object pooling. You might want to give it a go, it is old but definitely not outdated.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxm4a0QnQ9E

Answer (score 0):

You might need to keep a reference to the shot bullet, to be able to destroy with a coroutine after 3 seconds, it later on like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunShootingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public ParticleSystem MuzzleFlash;
public float damage = 10f;
public float range = 100f;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public float bulletLife = 3f;

private Queue<GameObject> myQ = new Queue<GameObject>(); //queue to keep track of the shot bullet and handle the delayed destroy
private IEnumerator coroutine;

void Start() {
    coroutine = DelayedDestroy(3f);
}
public Camera playerCamera;
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        //Destroy(bulletPrefab, bulletLife); Commented to avoid immediate destruction
        Shoot();
    }
}
void Shoot()
{
    MuzzleFlash.Play();
    myQ.Enqueue(Instantiate(bulletPrefab, playerCamera.transform.position, playerCamera.transform.rotation));
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.transform.position, playerCamera.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        TakeDamage target = hit.transform.GetComponent<TakeDamage>();
        if(target != null)
        {
            target.GiveDamage(damage);
        }

    }
    StartCoroutine(coroutine);

}

private IEnumerator DelayedDestroy(float waitTime) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    GameObject nullcheck = myQ.Dequeue();
    if (nullcheck != null) { //in case the queue is empty
        Destroy(nullcheck );
    }
    
}
}
```

Did not debug that, it is to give you the idea. You can check the [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?view=net-5.0) data structure and [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

Check pooling to achieve what you are making even better :)